# How to make Lambda + API Gateway obey REQUEST_URI?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, request-uri

I created an AWS Lambda with my application (a Web server) written in Rust Actix. I use https://crates.io/crates/lambda-web

Then I added this Lambda as the backend of an AWS HTTP API. The HTTP API has only `$default` stage.

https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ produces correct result (what my packaged Web server outputs when the root is requested).

But https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/p/YYY produces:
`{"message":"Not Found"}` what is surely not my Web server's output.

My task is to run the Web server in Lambda with path forwarded to the server in the normal way (as `REQUEST_URI`). So, when I request https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/p/YYY it should pass `/YYY` to my application. How?

Comment: Maybe, it can be done with Lambda@Edge?

Comment: Can I bypass reading origin and use only Lambda@Edge in CloudFront? Does Lambda@Edge follow the same standard as AWS HTTP API?